# cout derefernced (unsigned char) pointers, gives me unexpected results

Tags: c++

I need to take a peek at what's inside a declared unsigned char pointer, I reduced my problem to this short example

```
#include<iostream>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char;
    *buffer = 8;
    std::cout << "buffer = " << (unsigned char) (*buffer) << std::endl;
}
```

I am expecting this output : buffer = 8

But I get 
buffer =

Blank, which drives me nuts, not even any value !!!

**How I am actually dealing with it :**

```
#include<iostream>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint8_t * buffer = new uint8_t ;
    *buffer = 8;
    std::cout << "buffer = " << (int) (*buffer) << std::endl;
}
```

I am using this example in ns3 , *buffer* constructs a one byte payload packet, and I need it to be a **pointer**.
That's why I actually tagged my question as "C" along with "C++", because the core of the issue is also concerned in C. But I found myself down voted for that ! I know "cout" and "new" are c++ literals, but it's irrelevant to the issue !!

Not having a coding problem with all that, my problem is just what's ***unsigned char*** then if it reads as a regular char with cout !!!!!

I stated I am expecting it to be `buffer = 8` because unsigned char are one byte integers.

Thank you guys because you made me notice cout is dealing with it as if it is a regular char, despite it was expected for me otherwise.

Comment: 8 is the 8th character, not the character 8

Comment: @mahmoud You're not `cout`ing `unsigned char` pointers. Fix the title.

Comment: @LogicStuff: Yes he is. `*buffer` is an `unsigned char`, and `unsigned char) (*buffer)` is most definitely an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @barakmanos Not a pointer. I should have highlighted that. The memory leak should not be part of this MCVE.

Comment: @LogicStuff: Yes, not a pointer indeed.

Comment: what to you expect the ascii value '8' to output? it's not likely to be readable being very very much less than 20 (space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'8'` is the character 8.
`8` is just a code of a character which is invisible.

Try writing `*buffer = 48;` and guess why the output is "Buffer = 0" based on this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

Comment: Or possibly a backspace: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: How about suggesting code that is clear to humans? Devoid of magic numbers

Comment: @doctorlove. Most definitely a backspace. I don't remember my ASCII codes that well.

Comment: I looked it up.

Comment: Though most platforms rely on the same ASCII encoding, `'0' == 48` is nevertheless platform-dependent.

Comment: I get it, but (unsigned char) should be one byte integer numbers ?!

Comment: Same goes for `8` being "a code of a character which is invisible".

Comment: @mahmoudfathy Yes, it is one byte number, this is how character were (and still are) encoded on most platforms. The character in memory is just a byte and the table I linked gives you the idea of what number is interpreted as what character. The operator `<<` of `ostream` is implemented for `unsigned char` in such a way that it prints the character, not a number. If you want to see the number, cast the char to `unsigned int`.

Comment: So perhaps the question is more how do I see the ASCII value of an unsigned char, since `<<` is overloaded for `unsigned char` and shows me this as a character?

Comment: @riodoro1 I should have noticed this comment before I edit this "How I am actually dealing with it :" section. So it's all about << operator , just deceiving me by showing something not in context of my program !. Thanks riodoro1 anyway

Answer (score 3):

If we extend your example slightly to this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char;
    *buffer = 8;
    std::cout << "buffer = [" << (*buffer) << "]\n";
}
```

the output is

```
buffer = ]
```

The ASCII char 8 means backspace, and it has nuked the opening `[`.
Notice you don't need the cast to unsigned char - `*buffer` is an unsigned char.

If you want it to have the character `'8'` you need to set its contents to 8.
Don't forget to `delete` what you `new`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char;
    *buffer = '8'; //<---- see the single quotes?
    std::cout << "buffer = [" << (*buffer) << "]\n";
    delete buffer;
}
```

with output

```
buffer = [8]
```

Of course, we don't really need these pointers:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char buffer = '8';
    std::cout << "buffer = [" << buffer << "]\n";
}
```

And if you insist on using raw character codes:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char buffer = 56;
    std::cout << "buffer = [" << buffer << "]\n";
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If what you want to know is what numeric value is in the `buffer` variable and therefore want `<<` to report an integer value rather than stream this as a character, use a cast.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char buffer = 56;
    std::cout << "buffer = [" <<static_cast<unsigned int>(buffer) << "]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this just now ***unsigned()***:

```
#include<iostream>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char;
    *buffer = 8;
    std::cout << "buffer = " << unsigned(*buffer) << std::endl;
}
```

it gives the output I wanted in my question `buffer = 8`
which is not `buffer = '8'` as some might have thought I meant

Comment: That is a C-style cast to `unsigned int` (for historical reasons, the `int` part of the name is optional).